# How do I set a value to another variable in a class using get/set?

Tags: c#

I'm basically trying to set the id the same as the EventID. Both need to be able to be printed to the screen. Is it possible using something like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    public string id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = EventID; }
    }
}

static void main(string[] args)
{
    Event event = new Event();
    event.EventID = "something";
    Console.WriteLine(event.EventID);
    Console.WriteLine(event.id);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need a backing field. Right now you're looking at a stack overflow runtime error.

Comment: you could make one of them read-only and just make it return the other one when queried. Depends what the reason for this is - having two properties which both expose the same value is an interesting requirement. Are you trying to fulfil some interface definition?

Comment: Database requirement. It

Comment: OP I think you are looking for the [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value) keyword.

Comment: I'm still in the process of learning how it works. There's a mongo database I'm working with, and I need the id property set to something specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two properties for the same field like below:

```
public class Event
{
    string _id;
    public string EventID {
        get {return _id;}
        set {_id = value;}
    }
    public string Id
    {
        get {return _id;}
        set {_id = value;}
    }
}
```

Another way is the following as @PatrickRoberts has mentioned:

```
public class Event
{
    public string EventID {get;set;}

    public string Id
    {
        get {return EventID ;}
        set {EventID = value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `public string EventID { get; set; } public string id { get { return EventID; } set { EventID = value; } }`? Also you have a typo `Id` instead of `id`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts for me my example is more explaining that the idea is to have to properties for one field. I don't see any serious difference between your and my example. Also, I have not typo, I just write as with uppercase because convention for properties suggest it.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for Patrick: how to use the value keyword properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `id` always equals `EventId`, you can just make `id` a readonly property

```
public class Event
{
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    public string id { get { return EventId; } }
}
```

Another possible scenario is if you need `id` to be set when `EventID` is set, but it can also vary independently afterward:

```
public class Event
{
    private string _eventID;

    public string EventID 
    { 
        get { return _eventID; } 
        set { _eventID = id = value; }
    }

    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's for a JSON document. Both are required, and event id may change later.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.